# XML file is not displaying data properly for Google XML Live Data Feed

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to create an xml file for google live data feed in PHP language. But the problem is my xml file is not able to display the content properly. I guess my xml file is not valid. In Firefox, only two fields coming from mysql database is being displayed like below -

```
example.com
Google Merchant Feed
PM-3114-100 Smart Power Meter Single phase, 4 loops (60A)

Compact Single Phase Smart Power Meter, 4 loops, ModbusRTU protocol. 60A CT's.
050-063 62 ohm precision shunt resistor for 4-20ma transducer

62 Ω precision shunt resistor for use when monitoring 4-20mA transducers with Datascan 7000 modules. One required for each channel where 4-20ma transducers are required.
```

While in chrome and IE, there is no data is rendered but only the error is shown. In Chrome, I am getting the following error -

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 48 at column 9: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Here is my PHP code to create xml file -

```
<?php
// Set the xml header
header("Content-type: text/xml");

require_once '../admin/includes/login.php';
$sql =   "SELECT `p`.`products_id`, `p`.`products_name`, `p`.`products_url`, `p`.`products_short_desc`, `p`.`products_model`, `p`.`products_price`, `p`.`products_status`, `p`.`products_image`, `c`.`categories_name`, `b`.`brand_name` FROM `products` AS `p` LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON `p`.`categories_id` =  `c`.`categories_id` LEFT JOIN `brands` AS `b` ON `p`.`brand_id` =  `b`.`brand_id` LIMIT 1, 2";

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


// Echo out all the details
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>example.com</title>
<link>http://www.example.com/</link>
<description>Google Merchant Feed</description>'; 

// while loop, this will cycle through the products and echo out all the variables
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $sql2 = "SELECT `categories_id`,`products_url`,`products_name` FROM `products` WHERE `products_id` = " . $row['products_id'];
    $rs2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2);
    $categories_id = $row2['categories_id'];
    $structure = structure($categories_id);
    $structure = array_reverse($structure);
    $structure[] = $categories_id;

    $breadcrumb = '';
    $sub_url = $base;

    foreach($structure as $url) {
        $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `categories_name`,`categories_url` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories_id` = $url");
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3);
        if($url==0) {
            $breadcrumb .= '<a id="breadcrumb_home" href="'.$sub_url.$row3['categories_url'].'">HOME > </a>';
        } else {
        $breadcrumb .= '<a class="breadcrumb_link" href="'.$sub_url.$row3['categories_url'].'">'.$row3['categories_name'].' > </a>';
        $sub_url = $sub_url.preg_replace("/_c[0-9_]+/", "", $row3['categories_url']).'/';
        }
    }

    // collect all variables
    $brand = $row['brand_name'];
    $title = $row['products_name'];
    $link = $sub_url . $row['products_url'];
    $description = $row['products_short_desc'];
    $id = $row['products_model'];
    //$condition = $row['products_condition'];
    $condition = "new";
    $price = $row['products_price'];
    if($row['products_status'] == 1){$availability = 'in stock';} else {$availability = 'out of stock';}
    $products_image = $row['products_image'];
    $image = 'http://www.example.com/images/products/page/' . $products_image;
    $category = $row['categories_name'];
    //$gtin = $row['GTIN'];
    //$mpn = $row['MPN'];
    $gtin = 8808992787426;
    $mpn = "M2262D-PC";
    // output all variables into the correct google tags
    echo "<item> 
    <title>$title</title>
    <link>$link</link>
    <description><![CDATA[$description]]></description>
    <g:google_product_category>$category</g:google_product_category>
    <g:id>$id</g:id>
    <g:condition>$condition</g:condition>
    <g:price>$price GBP</g:price>
    <g:availability>$availability</g:availability>
    <g:image_link><![CDATA[$image]]></g:image_link>
    <g:shipping>
        <g:country>UK</g:country>
        <g:service>Standard</g:service>
        <g:price>5.95 GBP</g:price>
    </g:shipping>
    <g:gtin>$gtin</g:gtin>
    <g:brand>$brand</g:brand>
    <g:mpn>$mpn</g:mpn>
    <g:product_type>$category</g:product_type>
    </item>"; 
}
?>
```

I am investigating the problem at my best but not able to trace it. Please help me to find out the bug why the proper xml file is not creating and why the data is not being displayed in exact manner I want.

Answer (score 0):

The XML you generate is invalid. You do not escape the variables, so they can break it. The closing tags for channel and rss are missing, too. Use an XML API like XMLWriter or DOM.

Comment: Oh, i forgot to close channel and rss tags. But i dont understand how to escape variables?